# jQuery Resizable div transform matrix Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have this code and it is not right to resize the text in a div:

```
$('#resizable').draggable().resizable({
    resize: function(evt, ui) {        
        var width = parseInt(ui.element.css('width')),
        height = parseInt(ui.element.css('height'));
        ui.element.css({
            'transform': 'matrix('+(width/25)+',0,0,'+(height/25)+',0,0)'
        });
    }
});
```

[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/notepad77/yyv3du7o/)

is there any other way to do this, sorry for my English.